# How to stop reply to the user if the bot doesn't know what the user type in wit.ai?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, wit-ai

I am following this tutorial [wit ai messenger bot tutorial](https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-witai-tutorial)
My question is that how to stop reply if the bot doesn't know what the user typing to.Currently the bot is keep replying something what i structured in wit ai.

Please guide me

Comment: Can you provide more context? What do you mean by "unread style"? Do you have an example of something the user says and how you'd like your bot to answer (or not)? Thanks

Comment: yes,i dun want the bot answer,if it doesn't know .

Comment: Do you have any solution for that? please guide me,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your confidence in the answer. If it's below what you required, make a statement like "I'm sorry I can't answer that". Check your console inbox to see that everyone message has it's confidence meter.

Comment: See the output from wit.ai. It looks like this:

[
  {
    "_text": "remind me in 5 minutes",
    **"confidence": 1,**
    "intent": "default_intent",
    "entities": {
      "contact": [
        {
          **"confidence": 0.9974357783134485,**
          "type": "value",
          "value": "me",
          "suggested": true